# Is there a way to add routing to a web forms ASPX page that would use a custom PageHandlerFactory?

Tags: webforms, asp.net-routing

I have defined a custom HTTP handler the ".aspx" paths that extends the `PageHandlerFactory` ASP .NET class used to create web form page instances. It provides dependency injection to the web forms.

However, if add routing using the `RouteCollection.MapPageRoute(...)` method, ASP .NET uses the default page handler factory when the page is called by the route URL.

Is there a different way to add routes to web forms that would use the custom page handler factory?

I am using .NET 4.0, IIS 7.5 in integrated mode.